# Execute a method in main thread from event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, events, backgroundworker

I have a custom Queue class inherited from Queue class. It has an event ItemAdded. In the event handler of this event i am executing a method. But it is running other than main thread, though i want it in main thread.  I don't know how to do it. Any suggestion ?

```
//My custom class


using System;
using System.Collections; //Required to inherit non-generic Queue class.

namespace QueueWithEvent
{
    public class SmartQueue:Queue
    {

        public delegate void ItemAddedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

        public event ItemAddedEventHandler ItemAdded;

        protected virtual void OnItemAdded(EventArgs e)
        {
           if (ItemAdded != null)
           {
              ItemAdded(this, e);
           }
    }

    public override void Enqueue(object Item)
    {
        base.Enqueue(Item);
        OnItemAdded(EventArgs.Empty);
    }        

   }
}



 //Winform application

 using System;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using QueueWithEvent;

 namespace TestApp
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    SmartQueue qTest = new SmartQueue();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        qTest.ItemAdded += new SmartQueue.ItemAddedEventHandler(this.QChanged);
    }

    private void btnStartBgw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayThreadName();
        bgwTest.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void bgwTest_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                string valueTExt = i.ToString();
                qTest.Enqueue(valueTExt);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);

        }
    }


    private void DisplayThreadName()
    {
        string tName = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
        txtThreadName.Text = tName;           
    }

    private void QChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //#########I want this method to run on main thread #############
        DisplayThreadName();
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.
SKPaul.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are enqueueing items on background thread (DoWork event handler runs on background thread), thus your event raised also in background thread.

Use `InvokeRequired` method to verify if you are on UI thread. And if not, then use `Invoke` to run code on UI thread:

```
 private void QChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (InvokeRequired)
     {
         Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { QChanged(sender, e); });
         return;
     }
     // this code will run on main (UI) thread 
     DisplayThreadName();
 }
```

Another option for you - use `ProgressChanged` event to enqueue items (don't forget to set `WorkerReportsProgress` to true). This event handler runs on UI thread:

```
private void bgwTest_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    { 
        // use user state for passing data
        // which is not reflecting progress percentage
        worker.ReportProgress(0, i);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}

private void bgwTest_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     string valueTExt = e.UserState.ToString();
     qTest.Enqueue(valueTExt);
}
```

Comment: What if your main thread does not have a Form? For instance an ApplicationContext class for a tray application. Then Invoke is unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same approach as the `BackgroundWorker`, that is incorporating **[`AsyncOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperation.aspx)** as a member in your class, which can dispatch operations to a thread it has been created in.

```
protected AsyncOperation AsyncOp;
```

Instantiate it in your constructor with "null" argument. That creates an async operation "bound" to the current thread.

```
public SmartQueue()
{
    AsyncOp = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);
}
```

Then you can use the AsyncOp to `Post` your event.

```
public override void Enqueue(object Item)
{
    base.Enqueue(Item);
    AsyncOp.Post(OnItemAdded, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

That will execute the `OnItemAdded` handlers (subscribers) on the same thread that created the SmartQueue instance.

Answer (score -2):

Try with this code in main thread:

```
SmartQueue smartQueue = new SmartQueue();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    smartQueue.ItemAdded += new SmartQueue.ItemAddedEventHandler(smartQueue_ItemAdded);
}

void smartQueue_ItemAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add your code in here
}
```

Comment: This is simple event subscription, already done by OP. How does it solve multi-threading issue?

Comment: For multi-threading issue, you need to assign the delegate to temporary variable before testing and invoking it in order tobe thread safe. Maybe like this: `protected virtual void OnItemAdded(EventArgs e){ var temp=ItemAdded; if(temp!=null){ temp(this, e);}}`