# Update MVVM binding from event fired by asynchronous task

Tags: c#, events, mvvm, task

I have a task that runs a continuous TCP read operation, when that read operation reads a JSON encoded message from the remote server it will fire an event to the Command.cs class where it will handle the raw JSON and convert it into a Response class, do the necessary checks and then fires an 'Finished' event where ultimately the client subscribes to where they can receive a Response class that can be added to a Observable Collection.

I've tried to implement a RaisePropertyChanged that calls the Invoke function on the Dispatcher that should update the ObservableCollection properly.

### TCPRequest.cs

```
private static CancellationTokenSource cancellation;

private static event OnDataReceived datareceivedevent;

public static event OnDataReceived DataReceivedEvent
{
        add
        {
            if(datareceivedevent == null)
            {
                datareceivedevent += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            datareceivedevent -= value;
        }
    }

private static async void ReadOperation(object t)
    {
        var token = (CancellationToken)t;
        var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        var byteBuffer = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];

        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            int lRead = 0;
            if (stream.DataAvailable)
            {

                lRead = await stream.ReadAsync(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
            }
            if (lRead > 0)
            {
                var response = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(byteBuffer, 0, lRead);


                datareceivedevent(response);
            }
        }
    }
public static void StartReading()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(ReadOperation, cancellation.Token, cancellation.Token);
    }
```

The above code is the task that runs until a cancel is requested. When the data is available it will convert to string and will fire the event (showed above).

### Command.cs

```
public event OnDataReceivedDeserialized OnDataReceivedDeserialized;

public bool Execute()
    {
        this.JSONFormat = ToJson();

        TCPRequest.DataReceivedEvent += TCPRequest_DataReceivedEvent;

        if (!JSONFormat.Equals(string.Empty))
        {
            return TCPRequest.SendToServer(this);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The execute function is within a Command class that handles everything needed to send JSON to the server. This Command class subscribes to the TCPRequest datareceivedevent event.

```
  if (TCPRequest.IsConnected)
            {
                Command cmd = new Command();
                cmd.RequestCommand = new Request(RequestType.info);
                cmd.OnDataReceivedDeserialized += Cmd_OnDataReceivedDeserialized;
                cmd.Execute();  
            }

    public void Cmd_OnDataReceivedDeserialized(RequestResponse response)
        {
            LoPyList.Add(new LoPy() { name = "Test", id = "00" });
        }
```

And then above it will create the command that subscribes to the command event where the value of the server response will go.

### GraphViewModel.cs

```
private ObservableCollection<LoPy> lopyList;
    public ObservableCollection<LoPy> LoPyList
    {
        get { return lopyList; }
        set {
            lopyList = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("LoPyList"); }
    }
```

And lastly, above is the LoPyList that is binded to the interface combobox.

### GraphView.xaml

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LoPyList}" 
DisplayMemberPath="name"/>
```

The thing I need is that the function inside of the ViewModel updates the LoPyList and that I can view it in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your event fires, what you are doing is calling the "Add" method on the ObservableCollection:

`LoPyList.Add(new LoPy() { name = "Test", id = "00" });`

The problem here is that your `RaisePropertyChangedEvent` only occurs when you set the `LoPyList` property. When you call Add(), the setter does not run and so `RaisePropertyChangedEvent` is never called and your binding is never updated.

What you could do is add:
`RaisePropertyChangedEvent("LoPyList");` after you call Add():

```
public void Cmd_OnDataReceivedDeserialized(RequestResponse response)
{
    LoPyList.Add(new LoPy() { name = "Test", id = "00" });
    RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(LoPyList));
}
```

Alternatively, ObservableCollection exposes a [CollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event that

> Occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed.

You can hook into that event and then call `RaisePropertyChangedEvent("LoPyList");`

Comment: I have implemented this code into mine, but sadly this does not work. I get what you mean but what I am thinking is that the LoPyList gets updates in a background task which is not communicated to the 'client task'.

Comment: Ah I see..you'll need to ensure the callback runs on the main thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/13698748/2754727

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I initialize the viewmodel twice and use the second viewmodel that is not connected to the view. Afterward I used the dispatcher and it works like a charm.

Thanks for the help!